# Multiple i/o with an mutable object from different async requests

Tags: objective-c

This hasn't happened to me yet, but I found myself wondering if it is a problem for many different asynchronous requests to be inserting data into the same retained `NSMutableDictionary` or `NSMutableArray`. Is there any risk of two different methods simultaneously inserting data and somehow that receiving mutable object prevents access except for one process at a time?

In my case, I have an asychronous HTTP queue and as the responses come back from the Web, they are parsed and inserted into the same `NSMutableDictionary`. If you have a multiple requests doing this, potentially dozens or hundreds, is there a risk that something could fail because they are all simultaneously interacting with the same object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is always a risk when two threads can mutate data at the same time. For the most simple case you can use synchronization like this:

```
@synchronized (self) {
  [someMutabelArray addObject:someObject];
}
```

For more complex situation where `someMutabelArray` can be modified from many different methods you will need to use a `NSLock` or one of the other classes conforming to the `NSLocking` protocol that best suits your needs.